# Custom tagHelper based on counter from model in ASP.NETCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to render different text based on counter property from model.

```
int counter = 8;
```

I need a custom TagHelper:

```
//pseudo code
  if(counter > 8)
  {
    return "Foo"
  }
  else
  {
    return "Bar"
  }
```

The View should like something:

```
<li>
    condition-counter="@counter" //it should generate "Foo", or "Bar" depending on given counter
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your custom tag helper by following below steps:

1.MyContentTagHelper.cs

```
[HtmlTargetElement("my-content")]
public class MyContentTagHelper:TagHelper
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        //output.TagName = "span";    // Replaces <my-content> with <span> tag

       if(Counter > 8)
        {
            output.Content.SetContent("Foo");
        }
        else
        {
            output.Content.SetContent("Bar");
        }       

    }
}
```

2.View:

```
<li>
    <my-content counter="@counter" ></my-content>
</li>
```

3.Remember to add the addTagHelper directive to the Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file:

```
@using MyApp
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, MyApp
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-3.1